# installing react-native-sqlite-storage

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native

hello I am new with react native , i tried to install *react-native-sqlite-storage*
alter installing and i follow all instruction for android setup   :
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage][1]

i tried to run it using the command :react-native run-android , it all the time i am getting the error :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  What went wrong: Could not
>   determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.  Could not
>   resolve all task dependencies for configuration
>   ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>       Could not resolve project :react-native-sqlite-storage.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>          Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-sqlite-storage: None of the consumable configurations
>   have attributes.  Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack
>   trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
>   with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 1s Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected
>   and have set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
>   Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug Error: Command failed:
>   gradlew.bat installDebug
>       at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
>       at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
>       at runOnAllDevices (D:\RN\SqlApp1\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
>       at buildAndRun (D:\RN\SqlApp1\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
>       at isPackagerRunning.then.result (D:\RN\SqlApp1\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

could you advice how to sort this out ?
thanks

Comment: write your android configuration code here.

Comment: Step 2 - Update Gradle Settings (located under Gradle Settings in Project Panel)
// file: android/settings.gradle
...
 
include ':react-native-sqlite-storage'
project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.proj

Comment: Step 3 - Update app module Gradle Build script (located under Gradle Settings in Project Panel)
// file: android/app/build.gradle
...
 
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
}

Comment: import org.pgsqlite.SQLitePluginPackage;
 
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  ......
 
  /**
   * A list of packages used by the app. If the app uses additional views
   * or modules besides the default ones, add more packages here.
   */
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new SQLitePluginPackage(),   // register SQLite Plugin here 
        new MainReactPackage())
    }
}

Comment: Please add any additional information to your question.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

Go to your settings.gradle file and change THIS LINE

`project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/src/android')`

TO

`project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android')`

[refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695841/impossible-to-install-sqlite-on-react-native-project)