# Impossible to install SQLite on React Native project

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'd like to start a new React Native project including SQLite Storagee.

I've already done this before so I know that it should work, but not today...

So I've init a new project in which I installed react-native-sqlite-storage following this step by step tutorial (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage), the android part.

Everything is fine untill I run my project whith react-native run-android.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "pokedex",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.2.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Here is the result in my terminal. I don't understand what's going on.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-sqlite-storage.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-sqlite-storage:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-sqlite-storage.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-sqlite-storage:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/axel/leclercq.axel@gmail.com/Pokedex/Developpement - AXEL ONLY/V5/pokedex/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (/home/axel/leclercq.axel@gmail.com/Pokedex/Developpement - AXEL ONLY/V5/pokedex/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (/home/axel/leclercq.axel@gmail.com/Pokedex/Developpement - AXEL ONLY/V5/pokedex/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I've tried it with various version of both react-native and sqlite-storage but nothing works.

Need help please

Comment: Could you try `react-native link react-native-sqlite-storage` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help!

I tried it and nothing change, I've exactly the same response

Comment: Can you try the link after you rollback before installation?

Comment: Scuze me, I don't understand

Answer (score 3):

Hey I found the solution!
Just go to your settings.gradle file and change 
THIS LINE
project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/src/android')

TO THIS
project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android')

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks, that worked! It builds! 
But now a new problem came. 

On the emulator I have this:

Native module SQLite tried to override SQLitePlugin. Check the getPackage() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If it was you intention, set canOverrideExistingModule = true.

I checked and don't have it declared twice. I don't know where and how to set canOverrideExistingModule = true

Answer (score 0):

Same problem :( 
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :react-native-sqlite-storage.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-sqlite-storage: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Answer (score 0):

React Native also requires Java SE Development Kit (JDK). I installed it and then just restarted the program and the error was resolved. Hopefully this works for you as well!!
Greetings.